# how to get the data after displaying the table names using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES in sql?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was writing a query that selects the table name based on date,
Is there a way to get the actual data in a table after selecting the table name after using information_schema.tables?

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT('bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.', table_name)
  FROM bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_name = CONCAT('ga_sessions_', '20170801'))
```

This gets me the table name `'bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801'` only, not the actual rows

I do not want to manually copy & paste the table name, is there a way to write a query that directly gets the data in bigqueries?

Answer (score 0):

you can use BigQuery procedure to achieve your use case.

```
-- routine returning the results based on input table 
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE YOUR_DATA_SET.get_table_results (table_name STRING) 
 
 BEGIN
  -- Pass table name as parameter 

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
        SELECT * 
        FROM `%s` XX
  """, table_name);

END;

-- block to call the routine, here you can set the table name you want to return the rows

BEGIN
DECLARE table_name STRING;
SET table_name = (
SELECT concat(table_schema,'.',table_name) as table_name
  FROM YOUR_DATA_SET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access'
);
  CALL YOUR_DATA_SET.get_table_results(table_name);
END;
```